# Stop macro from throwing error if deletion criteria doesn't exist

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro below that deletes rows based upon criteria.  My issue is that if there is not any rows of data that meet the deletion criteria, it throws an error.  How do I get this to not throw an error if there are no rows to delete?

```
Public Sub Deletion()

    Dim wksData As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim rngData As Range
    
    'Set references up-front
    Set wksData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tester")
    
    'Identify the last row and use that info to set up the Range
    With wksData
        lngLastRow = .Range("V" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngData = .Range("V2:V" & lngLastRow)
    End With
    

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        With rngData
        
            'Apply the Autofilter method to the first column of
            'the range, using xlOr to select either
            .AutoFilter Field:=22, _
                        Criteria1:="Delete"
                        
            'Delete the visible rows while keeping the header
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
        End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    'Turn off the AutoFilter
    With wksData
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If .FilterMode = True Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
    
    'Let the user know the rows have been removed
    MsgBox "All Rows were removed.  Thank you!"

End Sub
```

Comment: You can wrap it with `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`

Comment: Hi there, wrap where ?  Want to make sure I don't get a syntax error.

Comment: Try `dim rngV as Range`, `On Error Resume Next` followed by `Set rngV = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and `On Error GoTo 0`. Then use `If Not rngV Is Nothing Then rngV.EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Or, use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to see if `Delete` is present in that column.

Comment: @BigBen I think `CountIf` will not return zero if a not visible range contains values... Did I wrongly understand what you meant suggesting?

Comment: @FaneDuru - I meant `CountIf` before filtering.

Comment: @BigBen I've  got it only now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `Range.SpecialCells` when deleting the visible cells.  A filtered range reference automatically only returns the visible cells.

```
Public Sub Deletion()
    Dim rngData As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tester")
        Set rngData = .Range("V2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    With rngData.CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="Delete"
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
        rngData.Parent.ShowAllData
    End With    
End Sub
```

Here is how to use `Range.SpecialCells`:

```
Sub DeleteVisibleRows(Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Target = Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then Target.EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```